# error when installing rubyzip in Ubuntu: requires >= 1.9.2

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I am using backtrack linux. Tried to upgrade BeEF project. Now it is missing some Ruby Gems and running bundle install gives the error:

> Gem::InstallError: rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

So I tried gem install rubyzip -v '1.0.0' and got the following:

> Error installing rubyzip:
>   rubyzip requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2

but... the command ruby -v gives me:

```
ruby 1.9.2dev (2010-07-02)
```

Tried to update ruby to 1.9.3 
so I'm not sure why rubyzip is giving that requirement and would be grateful for help. I edited the Gemfile and edited out the requirement for rubyzip and BeEF seems to work fine.

I'd still like to know the answer. I checked which ruby version bundler was using and it is 1.9.2dev. I read other answers to similar issues and consensus is to use RVM but it doesn't answer the question of why I can't install rubyzip.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it works for you, but I had the same message installing Redmine on Ubuntu. Turned out I had to install rails 3.2.13 (required by Redmine).

```
gem install rails -v 3.2.13
```